# how to typecast raw string into object type in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, casting, null

I hope everyone is doing good. I'm beginner in Javascript. I'm working in Node.js with oracle database. I am having array of objects. Ex: If any of the keys have null value in Javascript. **I want to replace dynamic text and then have to typecast a raw string into object type**.

I couldn't typecast raw string into object in javascript.

I have attached the code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

```html
var myObject = [
    {
        r_bu: '146',
        cty_code: 'AFG',
        c_code: 'AFN',
        ps_code: '146',
        b_unit: null
    },
    {
        r_bu: '6',
        cty_code: 'AGO',
        c_code: 'AOA',
        ps_code: '6',
        b_unit: null
    },
    {
        r_bu: '138',
        cty_code: 'BHR',
        c_code: 'USD',
        ps_code: '138',
        b_unit: 'OBU'
    },
    {
        r_bu: '138',
        cty_code: 'BHR',
        c_code: 'USD',
        ps_code: '665',
        b_unit: 'OBU'
    }
];

console.log(myObject);

function hasNull(element, index, array) {
    return Object.keys(element).some(
        function (key) {
            if (element[key] === null) {
                element[key] = `${element[key]} OR ${key} IS NULL` // I have replaced text wanna typecast string to object eg: 'null OR b_unit IS NULL' to null OR b_unit IS NULL
            }
        }
    );
}

myObject.some(hasNull);

console.log(myObject);
```

My Expectation like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31lfb.png)

Comment: You appear to have an XY-problem. You want to use `IS NULL` somewhere (but you have not told us where) and you think that means you need to convert the string `"IS NULL"` to an object. Show us what you are ultimately trying to do and not the tiny problem you think you need to solve and we can (probably) tell you why what you think you want to do is wrong (because the question you ask does not make sense as to why you would need an object to use as a filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem sounds like an XY-problem; however, if it really is as simple as wrapping a primitive string so that `typeof` reports it as an object then you can use:

```js
let a = new String("IS NULL");
console.log(typeof a)
```

Comment: Hi MTO, I have edited the question with detail explanation ,now you can see.